# Python Pandas merge multiple columns into a dictionary column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df_full) like so:

```
|cust_id|address    |store_id|email        |sales_channel|category|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567|123 Main St|10SjtT  |idk@gmail.com|ecom         |direct  |
|4567345|345 Main St|10SjtT  |101@gmail.com|instore      |direct  |
|1569457|876 Main St|51FstT  |404@gmail.com|ecom         |direct  |
```

and I would like to combine the last 4 fields into one metadata field that is a dictionary like so:

```
|cust_id|address    |metadata                                                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567|123 Main St|{'store_id':'10SjtT', 'email':'idk@gmail.com','sales_channel':'ecom', 'category':'direct'}   |
|4567345|345 Main St|{'store_id':'10SjtT', 'email':'101@gmail.com','sales_channel':'instore', 'category':'direct'}|
|1569457|876 Main St|{'store_id':'51FstT', 'email':'404@gmail.com','sales_channel':'ecom', 'category':'direct'}   |
```

is that possible? I've seen a few solutions around on stack overflow but none of them address combining more than 2 fields into a dictionary field.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html),

```py
columns = ['store_id', 'email', 'sales_channel', 'category']
df['metadata'] = df[columns].to_dict(orient='records')
```

And if you want to [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) original columns,

```
df = df.drop(columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `set_index`

```
df.set_index(['cust_id', 'address']).apply(dict, axis=1).reset_index(name='metadata')

   cust_id      address                                           metadata
0  1234567  123 Main St  {'store_id': '10SjtT', 'email': 'idk@gmail.com...
1  4567345  345 Main St  {'store_id': '10SjtT', 'email': '101@gmail.com...
2  1569457  876 Main St  {'store_id': '51FstT', 'email': '404@gmail.com...
```

---

#### comprehension

```
dat = [(c, a, dict(zip([*df][2:], m))) for c, a, *m in zip(*map(df.get, df))]
pd.DataFrame(dat, df.index, [*df][:2] + ['metadata'])

   cust_id      address                                           metadata
0  1234567  123 Main St  {'store_id': '10SjtT', 'email': 'idk@gmail.com...
1  4567345  345 Main St  {'store_id': '10SjtT', 'email': '101@gmail.com...
2  1569457  876 Main St  {'store_id': '51FstT', 'email': '404@gmail.com...
```