# Python Pandas merge multiple columns into a dictionary column with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741934/python-pandas-merge-multiple-columns-into-a-dictionary-column) asking how to merge multiple columns into a dictionary column, I'd like to know if this would be possible with conditions ?

Considering the following snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    {"line": "a", "price": 123, "details_1": "d1", "details_2": "d2"},
    {"line": "b", "price": 234, "details_1": np.nan, "details_2": "d2"},
    {"line": "c", "price": 345, "details_1": "d1", "details_2": np.nan},
    {"line": "d", "price": 456, "details_1": np.nan, "details_2": np.nan},
    {"line": "e", "price": 567, "details_1": "d1", "details_2": "d2"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

From [E. Zeytinci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741961/11701439) answer:

```py
cols = ["details_1", "details_2"]
df["details"] = df[cols].to_dict(orient="records")
```

Will merge "details_1" & "details_2" into a single col formated as dict with key as label which is almost what I need.

#### Firstly:

How do I do to add a condition, for instance I do not want to add "details_1" if its value is np.NaN but I still need to add "details_2" ?

#### Secondly:

Is it possible and if yes how do I do to apply a function to format the value, for instance to replace all "-", "_", " " by "" ?

#### Current Results

```sh
  line  price details_1 details_2                                 details
0    a    123        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
1    b    234       NaN        d2   {'details_1': nan, 'details_2': 'd2'}
2    c    345        d1       NaN   {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': nan}
3    d    456       NaN       NaN    {'details_1': nan, 'details_2': nan}
4    e    567        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
```

#### Expected Results:

```sh
  line  price details_1 details_2                                 details
0    a    123        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
1    b    234       NaN        d2  {'details_2': 'd2'}
2    c    345        d1       NaN  {'details_1': 'd1'}
3    d    456       NaN       NaN  {}
4    e    567        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested dictionary comprehension for remove values with `NaN`s:

```
cols = ["details_1", "details_2"]
df["details"] = [{k:v for k, v in x.items() if pd.notna(v)} 
                      for x in df[cols].to_dict(orient="records")]
print (df)
  line  price details_1 details_2                                 details
0    a    123        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
1    b    234       NaN        d2                     {'details_2': 'd2'}
2    c    345        d1       NaN                     {'details_1': 'd1'}
3    d    456       NaN       NaN                                      {}
4    e    567        d1        d2  {'details_1': 'd1', 'details_2': 'd2'}
```